# Convert AMD module dependency tree into file path list for Grunt task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, amd

I'm starting to use Grunt for JS builds.  Is there a tool available that automates walking an AMD module's dependency tree and outputs a list of file paths that can then be fed to a Grunt task?  This would be preferable to having to do all that manually.  Btw, I'm using CujoJS Curl and Bower.
Thanks much!

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs) or [this](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-bower-requirejs). Unfortunately right now GitHub is bugged for me, so I can't tell you if it'll fit 100% for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Both look like great solutions.  But they're for RequireJS, not CujoJS Curl, which is what I'm using.

Comment: Damn! I've seen AMD and automatically thought of Require :(

Comment: @gustavohenke On second thought, I just realized I might be able to use either of the Grunt plugins you suggested to package the modules, and still continue to use Curl within my app to load them.  After all, they'd still just be AMD modules.  I'm going to try it. Thanks!!!